# how do I prevent spring mvc overwriting sessionattributes from request

Tags: forms, spring, model-view-controller

I have an MVC spring application where the user logs on, this stores a User @SessionAttribute , which I refer to subsequently e.g. when updating a Customer object in a POST request I want the session User info to add to this object.
My problem is when I access the @ModelAttribute("user") User object in the customer POST, spring has bound request parameters into it i.e. the User.name has the value of the Customer.name from the submitted form.

NB I've kind of hacked this in that all controllers are subclasses of my AppController, which is where the @SessionAttributes are declared. But the principle would be the same if it was a single controller.

So can I prevent spring binding form:customer name value to User.name?

(I suspect webflow would be a more suitable framework for this, but don't have the time available right now to rewrite using this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can allow or disallow binding of certain fields of your model attributes using `@InitBinder`:

```
@InitBinder("user")
public void configureBindingOfUser(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setAllowedFields(); // No fields allowed
}
```

However, I don't think it's a good idea to use `@SessionAttributes` to store the current user or other similar objects. `@SessionAttributes`  was originally designed to maintain state of form-backing objects between `GET` and `POST` requests, not as a general purpose way to access a session.

Perhaps it would be better to use `session`-scoped beans or custom argument resolvers to access this kind of information.

Comment: Thanks. I've ended up explicitly storing in HttpSession. It's old skool, but so am I.