# Spring MVC + Hibernate: Partial model update from browser

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

When only displaying a part of a Spring MVC model bean, is there a way to only update in the model what comes back from the browser?

Let's say we have a User class (public properties only in this example, of course):

```
public class User {
  public String firstName;
  public String lastName;
  public String email;
  public Date subscriptionExpiration;
}
```

Now I display the first three properties as input fields in a JSP and want to update the object in the database accordingly. Only these 3 parameters should be updated, NOT the fourth one. One way to accomplish this would be

```
@RequestMapping("/user/{userId}", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveChanges(@PathVariable userId, User user, Model model) {
  User oldUser = User.loadFromDB(userId);
  oldUser.firstName = user.firstName;
  oldUser.lastName = user.lastName;
  oldUser.email = user.email;
  oldUser.saveToDB();

  model.addAttribute("user", oldUser);
}
```

but this would mean hardcoding all properties that could change, which I don't like too much.

Is there any way to determine what fields to update based on what the user was allowed to change? That mechanism should be smarter than just assuming that everything that's in the request parameters may be changed, otherwise any savvy user could manually inject additional fields into a request.

Using @Entity(dynamicUpdate=true) does not solve the problem either in my eyes, as I'm not getting the whole User object back in the request, and doing so would open up many security holes.

Am I missing a nice feature in Spring or is there any other way to conceptually solve for this problem? Any hints are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12597627/how-do-i-prevent-spring-mvc-overwriting-sessionattributes-from-request) to know how to use @InitBinder to allow/prevent some model fields to be bound by Spring to request parameters. This allows making sure that the `subscriptionExpiration` can't be modified by injecting a request parameter.

And see [the documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-methods) for how to use the @ModelAttribute annotation on methods and on method arguments to load a user from the database and add it to the model before the @RequestMapping method is called, and to populate this user with request parameters when the @RequestMapping method is called. This allows getting a user from the DB and have Spring populate it with ne values coming from the request. All you have to do is validate the new state of the user and save it to the database.

Answer (score 2):

I think the method

```
BeanUtils.copyProperties(Object source, Object target, String[] ignoreProperties)
```

does what you want. It copies all properties from one object to another without touching the properties defined in `String[] ignoreProperties`.

> Copy the property values of the given source bean into the given target bean, ignoring the given "ignoreProperties".
>
> Note: The source and target classes do not have to match or even be derived from each other, as long as the properties match. Any bean properties that the source bean exposes but the target bean does not will silently be ignored.
>
> This is just a convenience method. For more complex transfer needs, consider using a full BeanWrapper.

[API Documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.9/api/org/springframework/beans/BeanUtils.html#copyProperties%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29)

Comment: For the time being I have done something like this; I'm using custom annotations on the fields to steer whether they'll be updated and then parsing them to come up with a list of ignoreProperties. It works well, but I'd like to avoid defining this manually. Thanks for the input though!

Answer (score 0):

You can read the object from the database first and bind then the request. You can find an example at [FuWeSta-Sample](https://github.com/opensource21/fuwesta/blob/dff999c3689e2a44536b0ce4f6bf0a39cabca2a4/fuwesta-sample/src/main/java/de/ppi/samples/fuwesta/frontend/PostCRUDController.java#L279).

It uses a [helper-bean](https://github.com/opensource21/fuwesta/blob/dff999c3689e2a44536b0ce4f6bf0a39cabca2a4/fuwesta-core/src/main/java/de/ppi/fuwesta/spring/mvc/bind/ServletBindingService.java) which must be initialized by Spring.

Answer (score 0):

one option is to make use of hidden fields in your form. an option with draw backs but it works for some cases

Answer (score 0):

The nice feature you are looking for is [@ModelAttribute](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-modelattrib-methods). I assume that your form will also post the user id.

```
public class UserController {

    @ModelAttribute
    public User getUser(@RequestParam(value = "id", required = false) Long id) {
        return User.loadFromDB(id);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/user/{id}", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveChanges(@ModelAttribute User user, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            // return ...
        }

        //  model.asMap().clear();

        user.saveToDB();
        // return ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and finally resolve it by just adding a Type Converter.

```
public class AbstractDocumentConverter implements Converter<String, AbstractDocument> {

    private AbstractDocumentRepository abstractDocumentRepository;

    public AbstractDocumentConverter(AbstractDocumentRepository abstractDocumentRepository) {
        this.abstractDocumentRepository = abstractDocumentRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public AbstractDocument convert(String id) {
        return abstractDocumentRepository.findOne(id);
    }
}
```

I use mongodb,  AbstractDocument is the super class for all my Documents, in the controller I add @ModelAttribute("id") .

```
@RequestMapping("save")
public String save(@ModelAttribute("id") SportGame game) {
    sportGameService.save(game);
    return "redirect:/game/list";
}
```

It will first convert id to model(In my converter it find one from db by id), and then fill model fields from the request parameters.